# How to fully insert a new input + subsequent nodes in ONNX graph using helper utility?

Tags: python, onnx

I am trying to create a new input and subsequent node in the ONNX graph using the onnx.helper utility. I am able to correctly create the input tensor and node and insert the node into the graph.node list object. If I visualize the model in Netron it appears exactly as I want it but when using the onnx.checker.checkmodel() function it produces the issue of 'Nodes in a graph must be topologically sorted, however input 'tensor_name' of node: name: 'node_name' OpType: Conv is not output of any previous nodes. This issue does not appear if I insert new nodes in between the model input and the original 'input' node.
Please help me with what aspect I need to include in order to maintain the model's topological order when creating these extra inputs and subsequent node structures.
In the specific example: I am trying to replace a 'Min' type node with an equivalent structure (I am running the model on something that does not support Min nodes). Part of this is reshaping the data so I have created a new model input holding the new data shape -> then a reshape node that has this as an input + the 'Min' node original input. (I also tried using a const node instead of the model input as input to the reshape node).
The error comes up with this part of the graph when I specify the newly created input as a reshape node input, error of 'graph nodes must be sorted in topological order, input 'name_of_new_input' of reshape node not an output of any previous nodes' comes up.

```
    # not the actual code but shows where each variable comes from
    node_inputs = remove_node['inputs']
    shape = remove_node['shape']
    # The rest is actual code
    self.remove_node(node_name)

    const_in_shape = [1, 1] + [i for i in shape if i != -1] 
    min_layer_in = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info(f'input_for_min_layer_{i}',
                                                      onnx.TensorProto.FLOAT,
                                                      const_in_shape)

    const_layer_in = self.create_const_node(min_layer_in.name, const_in_shape)
    self.add_model_node(const_layer_in, insert_index)
    insert_index += 1

    self.model.graph.input.append(min_layer_in)

    # const_layer_in = self.create_const_node(min_layer_in.name, const_in_shape)
    # self.add_model_node(const_layer_in, insert_index)
    # insert_index += 1

    # new_dims_const_node = self.create_const_node(f'{new_dims.name}_const', new_dims.shape, new_shape)

    # (I know it looks like reshape is doing nothing here but in the actual code it reshapes the data)
    reshape_data = self.create_reshape_node(f'Reshape_{node_name}', const_in_shape, [min_layer_in.name], insert_index)
    self.add_model_node(reshape_data)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should take a look at this page. https://github.com/onnx/onnx/issues/2216